# how change my client request ip and forward to another website then return result to client with haproxy and dns

Tags: haproxy

I have a domain name serve with a ha-proxy server. i want when the clients set my domain name server in  their computer , when clients want to access ABC.com  or def.com their request forward to my ha-proxy server then request sent to ABC.com or def.com (with ha-proxy server IP) and give it back to client.
i don't want all request send over my ha-proxy just when they want to access "ABC.com" or "def.com".
I tried with "ngnix"  and do just with one website but i cant do with two or more. any  other solution will make me happier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok  finally i did with nginx but problem exist with https website . here my ngnix configuration :

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.myipaddress.com;
         location / {
                                proxy_pass http://www.myipaddress.com:80;
                                proxy_set_header Host $Host;
                                proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
                                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_Forwarded_for;
                                #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-proto $scheme;
                                }
}
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name  myiplocator.net;
         location / {
                                proxy_pass http://myiplocator.net:80;
                                proxy_set_header Host $Host;
                                proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
                                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_Forwarded_for;
                                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-proto $scheme;

                        }
}
```

but when i try with https website .https traffic doesn't go through  my reverse proxy  here my code :

```
server {
        listen 443;
        ssl on;
        server_name www.oracle.com oracle.com;
        ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/rpwildcard.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/rpwildcard.key;
         location / {
                                proxy_bind 'mynetwork ip  interface';
                                proxy_pass https://www.oracle.com;
                                proxy_set_header Host $Host;
                                proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
```